# 2 column DIV layout

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Simple 2 column div layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748178/simple-2-column-div-layout)
>   [2 column layout in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144375/2-column-layout-in-css)

I want to build a 2 column DIV layout. One of the columns should be right aligned and auto size and the other one should fill the left remaining space.

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried?

Comment: …and did you not see any of the related questions that appeared when you typed the title to this question into Stack Overflow?

Comment: Duplicate of [Simple 2 column div layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748178/simple-2-column-div-layout) or [2-column layout in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144375/2-column-layout-in-css) or [DIV only two-column CSS layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432304/div-only-two-column-css-layout) or (a large number of other related questions already on this site).

Comment: Don't put them in table. That's a terrible idea, and using CSS for it isn't that hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/UNgcd/2/?

HTML:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='right'>
        <p>some text goes here for auto width</p>
    </div>
    <div class='left'>
        <p>this takes up remaining space to the left</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

.left {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why setting 'margin-right' for the 'left' column isn't working?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/UNgcd/3/

Comment: Works in Google Chrome and FF but is not working in IE.

Comment: Can you clarify for all of us if my approach to your question is at least what you're looking for? Perhaps you should clarify your question as well.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for but my problem now is setting the 'margin-right' to the left column that it's not working as expected in IE

Comment: Remove the `margin-right` from the left dive and add `margin-left` to the right div. http://jsfiddle.net/UNgcd/4/

Comment: I know that setting the margin-left to the right column will work. But what is the explanation in IE margin-right for the left column is not working?

Comment: @ngen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1711/discussion-between-cornel-and-ngen)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="right">Auto sized right div</div>
<div id="left">Auto filling left div</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
   overflow: hidden;
}

#right{
   float: right;   
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/aCC7b/